# Entity Framework master-detail data entry without foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, master-detail

I have 2 tables `Orders` & `OrderDetails`. `Order` table has an identity `ID` column as its primary key. The `OrderDetails` table has the primary column of the `Order` table as a column.

I can't use foreign keys.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public long ItemID { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When I insert records, I want to get the primary key of the `Order` table to use in the `OrderDetail` table column. I'm inserting records in a single call. I want to rollback the insert into both tables if something fails.

Comment: Have you followed any EF tutorials, as this is fairly bread and butter stuff, research relationships, foreign keys and navigation properties. then how to insert records

Comment: I have used EF. Master/Detail insert is new to me. I tried to google also. still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DB generated Ids (like IDENTITY in MS SQL) you just need to add entity to ObjectSet and SaveChanges on related ObjectContext. Id will be automatically populated for you.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  context.MyEntities.AddObject(myNewObject);
  context.SaveChanges();

  int id = myNewObject.Id;
}
```

Each insert with Entity framework is followed by Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() which returns the auto generated Id for the newly inserted record.

However you can't get the auto generated Id before you save changes to the DB. If you want to do it all in a single transaction might i suggest you insert the records to DB by writing a custom stored procedure using transaction.